# ef core - how to make multiple variations of a class map to the same table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have 5 satellite assemblies with their own db contexts. I created a 6th the assembly just for code first migration. The idea was to add the satellite assemblies as references then create migration for all models. The quirk with this setup is that some of the satellite assemblies have same classes but with more or less properties(depending on whether they make sense in their respective **context**).

When I create a migration I get: `Cannot use table 'dbo.TableA' for entity type 'PartialClassA' since it is being used for entity type 'ClassA' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.`

I hope what I am trying to do make sense, my question is how do we make this work with code first?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is a response from the [ef core github forum](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13162)

Comment: I got the same issue when trying to use simplified classes (e.g. for dropdowns) for a table that already has full-feature classes. It seems, EF Core will support such scenarios in next version. I guess, for now the only way to solve this is to create SQL view for the "simplified" entities or use manual mapping in `Select()` projections.

Comment: You can also create multiple dbcontext, but then you have to make sure migration is only tracked in one of them.